# Is there such a thing as an escutcheon that will fit at an angle?

Tags: plumbing

I have a stub-out for my bathroom which exits the wall at a 45 degree angle (roughly).   The trap used to be in a vanity, but it's now exposed.  Is there such a thing as an escutcheon that will fit at an angle?

Comment: a picture would help

Comment: For the 1/2" water pipes or for the drain (size?) ?  Is it possible for them to exit the wall perpendicular and then bend 45 degrees once out of the wall?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have seen escutcheons shaped like this but don’t know where to buy.

It is possible you could modify one to accommodate the angle. Make the inner circle into an oval.

Comment: Why would an oval ?

Comment: @EdBeal, because a diagonal cross section of a cylinder has an oval shape.